Calling a public array
I am using a public array in my vba code which i filled the values in Test_String_Signaling macro then i wanted to call its values in another macro but i had the error subscript out of range
Here is where i filled the values of my public arrays:
Public Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID() As Variant
Public Sum_N_Handover_Per_CallID() As Variant
Public Sum_N_Eutran_Generated_Reason_Per_CallID() As Variant
Public Sum_N_Normal_Release_Per_CallID() As Variant
Public Sum_N_Authentication_Failure_Per_CallID() As Variant
Public Sum_N_Detach_Per_CallID() As Variant
Public Sum_N_Unspecified_Per_CallID() As Variant
Public Sum_N_Radio_Cx_With_UE_Lost_Per_CallID() As Variant
Public Sum_N_CS_FallBack_Triggered_Per_CallID() As Variant
Public Sum_N_Not_Enlisted_Reason_Per_CallID() As Variant

Sub Test_String_Signaling()
Dim N_Calls As Long
  N_Calls = Temporary.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
ReDim Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID(0 To N_Calls - 1)
' here there is a code that analyzes a string and then for each value
'    i increment a specific counter and this is an example of one counter:
 If Drop_Cause(Sigma_Lines(l - 1) + k + 2) = "02 02 80" Then
    N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID = N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID + 1
    'k is going from 0 to a maximum value previously calculated
     ' then after breaking from the loop k i put the result of the counter in the array like that:

Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID(l) = N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID
Debug.Print ("Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID = " & Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID(l))
Sum_N_Handover_Per_CallID(l) = N_Handover_Per_CallID
Sum_N_Eutran_Generated_Reason_Per_CallID(l) = N_Eutran_Generated_Reason_Per_CallID
Sum_N_Normal_Release_Per_CallID(l) = N_Normal_Release_Per_CallID
Sum_N_Authentication_Failure_Per_CallID(l) = N_Authentication_Failure_Per_CallID
Sum_N_Detach_Per_CallID(l) = N_Detach_Per_CallID
Sum_N_Unspecified_Per_CallID(l) = N_Unspecified_Per_CallID
Sum_N_Radio_Cx_With_UE_Lost_Per_CallID(l) = N_Radio_Cx_With_UE_Lost_Per_CallID
Sum_N_CS_FallBack_Triggered_Per_CallID(l) = N_CS_FallBack_Triggered_Per_CallID
Sum_N_Not_Enlisted_Reason_Per_CallID(l) = N_Not_Enlisted_Reason_Per_CallID

then i called the values after looking for the index "l" which i tested and is correctly returned,
dim N_User_Inactivity_Per_CellID as integer
N_User_Inactivity_Per_CellID=0
With Temporary
    Set FindRow = Temporary.Range("A:A").Find( _
         What:=Synthese_Global.Cells(i, 13).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With
FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row

N_User_Inactivity_Per_CellID = N_User_Inactivity_Per_CellID + _
             Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID(FindRowNumber - 2)

I think it has a problem of taking into account the values from the other macro Test_String_Signaling
any help is much appreciated!

Please include your variable declarations, and tell us the exact line where the error occured.   N_User_Inactivity_Per_CellID is this a typo? (Cell/Call)   If you're not using Option Explicit then you should be.

Subscript out of range can mean that the index is larger than the Ubound of the array. Break at FindRowNumber and in the immediate window ?Ubound(Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID). Check that it is greater or equal than FindRowNumber - 2

The naming conventions that were used in VBA and VB6 is something I really don't miss.

I updated the code, and i did msgbox(Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID(FindRowNumber) but it's the same error, you said i have to use option explicit, should i include it before the declarations "Public ..."?

I added the line option explicit before the public declarations and it's the same error at line N_User_Inactivity_Per_CellID = N_User_Inactivity_Per_CellID + Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID(FindRowNumber - 2)

Add MsgBox (FindRowNumber - 2) & "  Max = " & UBound(Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID)

@CDP1802: it gives me the same error at the line MsgBox (FindRowNumber - 2) & "  Max = " & UBound(Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID)

Please update your code to show exactly how you're populating those global arrays.  Whatever you're doing, it's not working.

@Tim Williams: I put debug.print right after filling fro example Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID(l) and it's filled correctly: this is the return of debug.print ==> Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID = 0

I think we've exhausted what we can suggest without your actual code though.  Clearly something is wrong, but we can only see what you've posted.

@Tim Williams: I added in the code the part in which i analyzes for example the counter N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID and by the end i put the result in Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID(l) l being the index of a CallID

And where do you set the dimensions of those global arrays?

can you just give an exmaple of how would you do this: 1st declare public array Array(), 2nd Fill Array in macro1() then call for each i from 0 to Ubound(Array,1)-1 use Array(i) in macro2

Your first sentence is "I am using a public array in my vba code which i filled the values in Test_String_Signaling macro".  Does that code actually run?

@Tim Williams: the code works and i added the redim line before entering the loop l in which i fill the arrays

@CDP1802: the brackets are necessary to declare it as an array i think! and the array Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID() is filled correctly in macro Test_String_Signaling but won't be called or whatever the problem with the dimension in the other macro that's my problem

guys how would you do it? can you show me an example where you declare a public array and fill it in macro1 then call its values in macro2 please?

I think the problem is in the row number finding in this: 'With Temporary
Set FindRow = Temporary.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Synthese_Global.Cells(i, 13).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With
FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row' is it correct? I want to find Synthese_Global.Cells(i, 13).Value in column A in Temporary sheet

"can you show me an example where you declare a public array and fill it in macro1 then call its values in macro2 please?"
For example:
Option Explicit

Public Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID() As Variant

Sub Tester()
    
    ReDim Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID(1 To 3)
    
    Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID(1) = "one"
    Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID(2) = "two"
    Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID(3) = "three"
    
    Tester2
End Sub

Sub Tester2()
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = LBound(Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID) To _
            UBound(Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID)
        
        Debug.Print i, Sum_N_User_Inactivity_Per_CallID(i)

    Next i
End Sub


what does mean the line "Tester2" in Tester macro?

It runs Tester2  Same as the (deprecated) Call Tester2()

okey, so if I'm calling Tester2 under a private Sub which is included in worksheets Synthese_Global does it change anything? Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$1" And Target.Value <> "" Then
Call Tester2

That should work fine.  FYI you're capturing the worksheet SelectionChange event - it you want to respond to changes in cell values then you want the Change event
